# How to group by so duplicates are not counted

Tags: sql

I have this query :

```
select resorti.resort_id
      ,resorti.resort
      ,hoteli.resort_id
      ,hoteli.hotel_id
      ,hoteli.hotel
  from resorti 
       inner join 
       hoteli on resorti.resort_id = hoteli.resort_id
```

How do I change this query so that the name of the resort is listed only once if there are many resorts with the same name ?

Edit: I altered the query. Here are the actual results :

[image]

Here are the desired results:

[image]

Comment: Please give an example of the results that you want to see.  Also tag the question with your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the resort info but you'll lose the detail you want on the hotels.

Truly you are better suppressing the "duplicate" resort entry in you application layer.

You could generate row number within each group in a derived table and then query that suppressing the resort when row number <> 1, but the syntax would depend on your rdbms.

Edit:

against my better judgement, here's how you could do it in sql sever. same is possible without tsql's row_number or a cte, it's just more concise.

```
create table resorti (resort_id INT, resort VARCHAR(50))
create table hoteli (hotel_id INT, resort_id INT, hotel VARCHAR(50))

insert into resorti values (1,'resort_1'),(2,'resort_2')
insert into hoteli values (1,1,'hotel_1a'),(2,1,'hotel_1b'), (3,2,'hotel_2a'),(4,2,'hotel_2b')


;with cte as (
  SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY resort_id ORDER BY hotel_id) rn
    FROM hoteli
)
select case when rn=1 then resorti.resort_id end resort_id
      ,case when rn=1 then resorti.resort end resort
      ,resorti.resort
      ,cte.hotel_id
      ,cte.hotel
  from resorti 
       inner join 
       cte on resorti.resort_id = cte.resort_id
```

Comment: This is absolutely a job for the application layer, not the query.

Comment: agree...will see...:(

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information of your database... If you group by `resort` and there are two rows with same name but different `resort_id` then a group is only possible if you don't select the `resort_id`. Or your second selected column of table `resorti` is calculated by one of these functions: SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, and COUNT

Try something like this

```
SELECT
    resorti.resort,
    hoteli.hotel_id,
    hoteli.hotel

FROM resorti

INNER JOIN hoteli ON resorti.resort_id = hoteli.resort_id

GROUP BY resorti.resort
```